# No green squiggly line under obsolete properties, no warnings during build either ... VS2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

When I will be removing/changing a property I usually mark it obsolete so VisualStudio will show a green squiggly line under the propertyname wherever it's shown in code. It also generates a warning during compilation.

I've noticed that in VS2017 this doesn't happen, does anyone know how I can get this behaviour back to how it was (and should be in my opinion) ?

thanks,
Jurjen.

Comment: Hm, I get the warning and see the squiggly lines.  Maybe you have an extension installed that's altering VS' behavior?

Comment: I do have Coderush (devexpress) installed.

Comment: Can you (temporarily) disable it, just to rule it out as a suspect?

Comment: I do notice that you will only get the warning / squiggles if you attempt to reference the decorated class member.

Comment: Also check your project settings, make sure you aren't telling the compiler to ignore warnings 612 and 618.

Comment: Turned CodeRush off, doesn't make a difference.

Comment: If you decorate a class member with `Obsolete` but refer to the member through an interface, you won't get the squiggles either.  Decorating the interface will, though.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that when you override a property and mark it as obsolete,

```
[Obsolete("...")]
public override int SomeId {get;set;}
```

Then no green squiggly or compiler warning, seems to have to do with the override as in the base class it's not obsolete

```
[Obsolete("...")]
public new int SomeId {get {return base.SomeId;} set {base.SomeId=value;} }
```

using 'new' does the trick, green squiggly's and compiler warnings.

Comment: `new` and `override` are profoundly different. Of course you get compiler warnings. The solution to a missing compiler warning isn't to rewrite your code so there are bugs in it.